# Why do we see Spotify logs in Logcat?

Tags: android, spotify, logcat

I am developing my own Android app, and, strangely, I see some logs related to Spotify in the Logcat.
Why is this ? Does it mean that apps' logs can be that easy to intercept ? Can we prevent this from happening ?

**EDIT**

Ok. I tried to re-test this several times. It seems that it is not related to my app. But, each time I plug my USB cable into my smartphone, many Spotify logs appear (Warnings and Errors mainly).
Here are some examples :

```
E/Spotify: [RxCachedThreadScheduler-1] Could not retrieve access token for a webgate request: POST https://spclient.wg.spotify.com/gabo-receiver-service/v2/events
E/Spotify: [RxCachedThreadScheduler-1] sp://webgate/v1/token responded with an error: 39, ap_network_disabled
E/Spotify: [OkHttp https://spclient.wg.spotify.com/...] sp://webgate/v1/token responded with an error: 39, ap_network_disabled
E/Spotify: [OkHttp https://spclient.wg.spotify.com/...] Could not retrieve access token for a webgate request: GET https://spclient.wg.spotify.com/quicksilver/v2/triggers
W/ProcStatsManager: No process com.spotify.music/10128 for service com.spotify.mobile.android.service.SpotifyService
W/ProcStatsManager: No process com.spotify.music/10128 for service com.spotify.music.storylines.service.StorylinesFetcher
W/ProcStatsManager: No process com.spotify.music/10128 for service com.spotify.mobile.android.spotlets.ads.marquee.MarqueeService
W/ProcStatsManager: No process com.spotify.music/10128 for service com.spotify.mobile.android.service.feature.FeatureService
W/ProcStatsManager: No process com.spotify.music/10128 for service com.spotify.music.features.podcast.episode.experiment.EpisodeMetadataFetcher
W/ProcStatsManager: No process com.spotify.music/10128 for service com.spotify.music.behindthelyrics.service.BehindTheLyricsResourcesAndTracksFetcher
```

Comment: You're probably viewing your phone logs instead of your app's log. To let LogCat display only your app's log, Click on the drop-down options after Regex and select "Show only selected application". You should now see logs for only your app.

Comment: My logcat is set to "Show only selected application", and yet, I get these logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @DevMike01 has said, you should probably change your logcat to show logs for your application only :

[image]

the reason why this is happening is probably because you are connected to your own device and you are viewing all the logs and events for your own device, not just for your own application

you can do this by clicking on the dropdown (which is red in the example and selecting your app instead)

as an extra, logging in production is a bad idea, as this is an example as well, and you might want to consider using Timber as an alternative to normal logs IF YOU WANT TO (this is a pretty standard logging util for android now https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber)

Answer (score 2):

If this is a problem for your app, and you are willing to strip down the app's logs in production you may use Proguard for example (https://medium.com/@trionkidnapper/stripping-log-statements-using-proguard-73dedc68ee97)

Also most commercial obfuscators support stripping the logs.